# getComputedStyle property values

Tags: javascript, css, getcomputedstyle

I'm trying to report the value of my border radii of an oval div I created, but I'm getting an undefined value returned. Can anyone explain why? Am I making a simple mistake or is there something wrong with my code? Thank you!

```
<!DOCSTYLE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS3</title>
    <style>
        #oval{
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
            background: black;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
            border-top-left-radius: 50%;
            border-top-right-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var myOval = document.getElementById('oval');
        var bRadBL = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-bottom-left-radius");
        var bRadBR = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-bottom-right-radius");
        var bRadTL = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-top-left-radius");
        var bRadTR = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-top-right-radius");
        var bRad = getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("borderRadius");
        function compStyle(){
            alert("Top Left Radius: "+bRadTL+"\nBottom Left Radius: "+bRadBL+"\nTop Right Radius: "+bRadTR+"\nBottom Right Radius: "+bRadBR);
     }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="oval"></div>
    <input type="button" value="click me" onClick="compStyle()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I've tried both "border-bottom-left-radius" and "borderBottomLeftRadius" with the same results. Which one am I supposed to use?

Comment: Your script is executed before the element even exists. Move the part above `function compStyle(){` into the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run the script before the elements are rendered. Move the script block to the end of the body, after the html element id declared:

```css
#oval{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="oval"></div>
<input type="button" value="click me" onClick="compStyle()"/>

<script>
  var myOval = document.getElementById('oval');
  var bRadBL = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-bottom-left-radius");
  var bRadBR = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-bottom-right-radius");
  var bRadTL = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-top-left-radius");
  var bRadTR = window.getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("border-top-right-radius");
  var bRad = getComputedStyle(myOval).getPropertyValue("borderRadius");
  function compStyle(){
    alert("Top Left Radius: "+bRadTL+"\nBottom Left Radius: "+bRadBL+"\nTop Right Radius: "+bRadTR+"\nBottom Right Radius: "+bRadBR);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I must have missed the part in my textbook that explains this. Although I'm sure I didn't and it's a terrible textbook (anything to make me feel like a better programmer and sleep better at night). Thanks again!

Comment: lol. It's basics, so if the book doesn't contain it, ditch the book. Anyway, maybe the book referred to this [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).